# Python. Как сделать прогресс бар на фотографии?

Tags: python

Можно ли это сделать?
Например

```
T = 2000
T2= 1500
```

Как сделать что бы код сделал фотографию с прогресс баром на котором прогресс от 1500 до 2000

Comment: что значит "от 1500 до 2000" - не понятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

прогресс бар это 2 прямоугольника?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
im = Image.open('image.jpg').convert('RGBA')

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

persent = 300*1500/2000

draw.rectangle(((10, 10), (persent+10, 40)), fill="#8888ff")
draw.rectangle(((10, 10), (310, 40)), outline="#ff8888", width=2)

del draw

im.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`((10, 10), (persent+10, 40))` - координаты `[(x0, y0), (x1, y1)]`

Comment: А где можно указать координаты, где будет нарисован прогресс бар?

Comment: первый параметр на фунуции draw.rectangle это [(x0, y0), (x1, y1)]